# In Kingdom Hearts, what counts as "Items Used"?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

When I finish Kingdom Hearts (PS2 Greatest Hits release) on Expert mode, after the credits and epilogue cutscenes, there's a screen that shows various statistics, such as Heartless Defeated, number of times Sora took damage, etc.  One of these is "Items Used".

But what exactly counts toward this "Items Used" statistic?  Does it include:

- Sora uses a consumable (Potion, Ether, up to Megalixir) from inventory, in or out of combat?
- An ally uses a consumable in combat?
- A consumable (which could be in inventory) is used directly from stock out of combat?
- The party uses a stock-only HP/MP restoration object (Tent, Cottage, etc.)?
- Sora uses a stat booster (Power Up, Defense Up, AP Up)?
- An ally uses a stat booster?
- Sora gives an item to a flower in Wonderland's forest?
- An item is consumed by the "recipe" or "experiment" in Deep Jungle's Camp area?
- Anything involving unique plot-related or puzzle-related items?

Comment: After my 10+ years playing Kingdom Hearts, not once have I thought about this...

Comment: Never even noticed that in the credits, but I wonder this too, now.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Anything in Active Inventory or originating from your stock is considered an item. Gifting/transferring an item doesn't count unless that item's specific effect was proc'd.

**Long Version:**

This question is very tough- the only two ways to 100% be certain is to play through multiple times keeping track of what you use, or two use a mod tool to view where the game stores 'items used.'

I looked at several sources for what Kingdom Hearts defines as an 'item,' and I found several references that corroborate what I had suspected- Items are defined as anything that can be stored in stock or active inventory, and item use is only proc'd if that item's effect is initialized (not necessarily triggered).

First, I found an old IGN guide ([here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdom-hearts/Basics)) that items must be used from "the sub-menu" and are stored in the main stock, and must then be shifted to the active inventory.

Next, I found a wonderful guide put together by /hardcore rpg gamer/ ([here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/915410-kingdom-hearts-ii/faqs/42384)) that itemized the types of items you may encounter in the game:

- AP Boost
- Defense Boost
- Drive Recovery
- Elixir
- Ether
- Hi-Potion
- High Drive Recovery
- Potion
- Magic Boost
- Mega-Ether
- Mega-Potion
- Megalixir
- Power Boost
- Tent
- Torn Page

Lastly, I looked up the definition in the Item Page of the original Strategy Guide for Kingdom Hearts (found the PDF on a old site that I will not post due to copyright issues). It defined items somewhat nebulously, referring to weapons occasionally as items, yet having separate pages for both items and weapons. However, on the main item page it says: "Items may be stored in your main stock, your active inventory, or the inventory of a party member." I believe this fits my definition.

**CONCLUSION:**

Anything in Active Inventory or originating from your stock is considered an item. Gifting/transferring an item doesn't count unless that item's specific effect was proc'd. In addition, keyblades, synthesis items, and accessories do NOT count as items used, but summon charms do.

Comment: Your second link is about Kingdom Hearts II, not Kingdom Hearts. KH has no "Drive Recovery", and has a number of common and unique items not on that list. I'm asking more about what "used" means, not what "item" means. So do you know what "item use is only proc'd if that item's effect is initialized (not necessarily triggered)" means in terms of actual game actions?

Comment: The type of item doesn't matter- it matters where that 'item' is stored: if the item is stored in your main stock or active inventory, then it will count as used once you activate it from your battle menu. I believe I answered most cases of 'use,' but it really does matter more what the item is than when it is used. As I said in my response, activating an item from the battle menu is the only way to count it as a use. In response to each of your specific cases in your question: yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, no, no, no/it depends (respectively).